# Inconsistency About Omitting 'return' Keyword to Return Closure Block in Groovy

Tags: groovy, return, closures, keyword

I've just started learning Groovy. And I got into this: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_return_keyword_optional
So, 'return' can be omitted at the end in a method definition. Alright.
Even though I would prefer using it personally, I wanted to take a look.
I tested some simple cases to figure out how it works:

e.g. demo.groovy:

```
def a1 = { return { return 'hi'} }()
println a1

def a2 = { return {'hi'} }()
println a2

def a3 = { {'hi'} }()
println a3

def a4 = { {-> 'hi'} }()
println a4
```

I ran the script, and the result was:

```
demo$_run_closure1$_closure5@21c64522
demo$_run_closure2$_closure6@460f76a6
hi
demo$_run_closure4$_closure7@1922e6d
```

Starting from the case **a1**, I omitted keywords 'return' one at a time. They are the cases **a2**, and **a3**.
What made me scratch my head is the case **a3**. I expected the closure to be returned like the cases **a1** and **a2**. But it returned 'hi', not the closure itself.
So I added another test case **a4** and then it worked as expected.

I tried to search some documentation about it, but couldn't find a proper one.
Why does it return 'hi' not a closure object?

Thanks in advance.

FYI, my groovy version is:

> Groovy Version: 3.0.7 JVM: 15.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

Comment: This goes down even deeper: `{{{{{{42}}}}}}()` also gives 42

Answer (score 5):

What you see in the `a3` example is not a nested closure, but a nested code block instead.

> ### Nested code blocks
>
> An infrequently used structure within Java is the anonymous code block. It’s generally not encouraged as it’s often a sign that refactoring the related code into a method is in order. But it’s sometimes useful to restrict scoping and is now available in Groovy:
>
> ```
> {
>     def a = 1
>     a++
>     assert 2 == a
> }
> try {
>     a++ // not defined at this point
> } catch(MissingPropertyException ex) {
>     println ex.message
> }
> {
>     {
>         // inner nesting is another scope
>         def a = 'banana'
>         assert a.size() == 6
>     }
>     def a = 1
>     assert a == 1
> }
> ```
>
> Be aware though that in Groovy having a code block looking structure after any method call will be seen as an attempt to pass a closure as the last parameter in the method call. This happens even after a new line. So it’s safe to start an anonymous code block after any other block (e.g. an if-then-else statement or another anonymous code block). Anywhere else and you might need to terminate the previous statement with a semicolon. In which case, see the note above about refactoring your code! :-)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#_nested_code_blocks</sup>

You can run this script in the `groovyConsole` and go to "Script" -> "Inspect AST" to see what the compiler produces in this case:

[image]

You can see that `a3` is a closure that implicitly returns `'hi'`.

The support for nested code blocks was added in Groovy 3. If you run the same example in Groovy 2, you would see the following compilation error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/wololock/workspace/groovy-3-sandbox/src/main.groovy: 7: Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;
   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 7, column 12.
   def a3 = { {'hi'} }()
              ^

1 error
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Now it's so clear. BTW, isn't it better to include it in the language specification, not just a release note? As a newcomer, I expected the language spec is as complete as JLS. And I don't know about Groovy 2 at all, but Groovy 2's error message like "Ambiguous! a closure or a nested code block?" is a lot clearer than Groovy 3's counterintuitive default at least to me.

Comment: @SillyQuestioner AFAIK there is no formal spec.  Before this changel, which I totally missed, the rule of thumb was basically: if you see `{}` it's a closure unless near one of the keywords (try, for, class, ...). I also don't like this change.